# How do I remove an account from Google multi-login?

Tags: google-account, google-multi-login

I have three accounts among the multiple accounts I have for Google's products. One of them belongs to a friend who accidentally made his account one of mine when he was using my PC.

How do I remove his account from my Google multiple accounts? Logging out from his account doesn't work. His account still displays under the user dropdown even though I can't log in to it.

Comment: Does your friend's account name appear in the username field in the login screen? If so, that's the browser caching his account name.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have two accounts logged in as well. If I go to google.com, click 'Log out', it logs me out from all accounts. I have to login back with some account and the second is not visible in the menu that time.

So I assume logging out logs you out from all accounts and required you to login with each of them separately again. (Because of this I don't understand why you say logging out doesn't work.)

Comment: Hmm, yep, I logged out of everything and logged myself back in, and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I had to first login and then do this.  For some reason then the remove button showed up, but it wasn't there before I logged in and then logged out again.

Comment: This didn't work for me. But Ang's answer did.

Answer (score 17):

Follow these steps to remove other accounts from your computer:

1. Open a new tab and type in Google.
2. Sign out of your account in that tab.
3. Click the blue sign in button in the upper right corner.
4. This will bring up all accounts on your computer and there will be an add account option on the bottom left or a delete account option on the bottom right.
5. Click the delete option.
6. Click on the accounts you wish to remove from your computer.
7. Click done.
8. Sign back into your Google account.

Answer (score 3):

I have two accounts linked together as well. To remove it:

1: Go to google.com and log out. It doesn't matter from what account, it logs you out of all of them.

2: Refresh the page, and click login.

It will ask you to choose an account. From here, click 'remove' and then the X beside the account(s) that you want to remove.

Answer (score -1):

**If you want to remove an account from the account list do the following:**

1. Click on `Sign out` in the account list.
2. Google will now be signed out. Click on the `Sign in` Button on the top right corner of the page.
3. At the bottom of the page, you will see a `Remove an account` button. Click that.
4. Google will ask you what account to remove. Select the one to remove and click on `Confirm`.
5. Now, log back into your Google account.