# How do I NOT stay signed-in in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-account

What bothers me is that Gmail keeps me signed in until I sign out. I would like it to automatically sign me out after some time. YouTube and other Google accounts can stay signed in, but with Gmail service, in particular, I don't feel safe to stay signed in.

I don't see any way to set this in [my security settings of Google Account](https://myaccount.google.com/security?utm_source=OGB&utm_medium=act#).

Perhaps it could be done by [setting the expiry time of Gmail cookies](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/yUR6LYe0XCQ)? Not sure how to do it though.

[Google seems to provide setup of session length actually](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7576830?hl=en), but this probably does not apply to Gmail / normal Google Account (?)

Answer (score 2):

You have three options:

## **1. browser auto logoff on exit**

By removing your browsing history as soon as you close the browser, this makes sure that no one sees or uses your history if you are sharing the same computer, you have to search **`inetcpl.cpl`** in run menu - **<kbd>WINKEY</kbd>** + **<kbd>R</kbd>** - there you will get Internet properties menu there you have to select **Delete browsing history on Exit** and then **OK**

[image]

## **2. cookie auto logoff by blocking**

You can block most cookies while still allowing them from certain sites. With this exceptions, you can auto log out from Gmail or other webmails.

- on your computer, open Google Chrome
- in the top right, click the **Menu**
- click **Settings** and then **Show advanced settings**
- in the "Privacy" section, click **Content settings**
- under "Cookies," click **Manage exceptions**
- enter the site name you want to allow cookies for. to allow cookies from an entire domain, insert **`[*.]`** before the domain name. for example: **`[*.]google.com`** - this creates an exception for:

  - `mail.google.com`
  - `drive.google.com`
  - `calendar.google.com`
- you can also put an IP address or a web address that doesn't begin with `http` / `https`
- use the menu to choose whether the site can set cookies. If you select **Clear on exit**, its cookies are deleted every time you close your browser and your mail session will end too

## **3. auto logoff extension**

Auto Logout extension automatically logs you out of all logged in accounts upon closure of all browser windows in case you forget to sign out. This extension is recommended for use in shared computers to keep different accounts safe. You just need to add the extension. What this extension does is, it simply logs out from websites once you close Google Chrome. That means you have to log in every time you open up your Chrome browser

**[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-logout/ohlcnddhihadnalofegeookbpglgadhe)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks but honestly, I am not fan of these methods. I think it is very dangerous. I would get used to be signed out automatically, and then I come to different computer - and I will stay signed in!!! No no no, this is not a solution. Automatic sign out must be a property of the account itself, not particular browser. I.e. server, not client based security.

Comment: well, the thing is that there is no such property or option which would sign you out

Comment: OK, so the answer is basically "it is not possible" - fair enough. Thanks for the workaround.

Comment: @Tomas you are welcome. the issue is that google expect from enduser to use either incognito mode or guest mode while on a different computer

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to stay signed in (on a PC) on YouTube but not on Gmail. Such selective logins are not provided. Also, there is no feature such as an automatic sign-out. The session won't expire by itself. You need to manually logout. To stay logged out when you reopen your browser, enable the 'delete cookies on exit' feature.

On a mobile device too, there is no option to logout in the pre-installed Google apps. Once you login, you stay logged-in forever until you reset your device; or change your password. However, you may logout if you are using 3rd party apps or any other Google app that can be uninstalled, or if you have logged in from your browser.

Comment: Of course it is possible! Just present different session cookies to YouTube than to GMail!
By using a different browser, a privacy mode, or some browser features (like selective per-site cookie blocking). If all else fails, a VM or a whole different machine will certainly make it possible.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

It's not possible to sign out from one single Google service and kept signed in on another Google service.

## Explanation

Most Google apps use the the same sign in credentials what make it possible that once we sign in into one service we could jump to another service without having to sign in again but the same happens the other way, once we sign out on one service we don't have to sign out on the other services.

The workaround has two parts:

- First: use two different accounts one for Gmail and another for the other services
- Second: use two different web browser profiles or two different web browsers, one for Gmail, the other for the Google account to be used for the other services.

References

- [How do I remove an account from Google multi-login?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/28760/88163)

Comment: Hi Ruben! OK, thanks for this information. This explains it. In this case, I wouldn't take the road of separating my gmail account. Anyway, your answer does not address the actual problem of staying signed in - do you have better solution than the one of user0's?